# Bing maps get Distance between two places

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, bing-maps

I have referred the sample http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#BingRouting and developed a Bing maps routing tool on my Silverlight GIS website.. now my client wants me to also show the distance between two places whos direction is shown..

I took a look at the Routing class but failed to find anything to get the distance.. I used the ‘haversine’ formula, but it does not give me the exact distance along the route..

or

Can I calculate the length of the geometry/polyline drawn on the map.. Will this result be accurate? Please guide me so that I can get the distance between my start and destination..

Comment: Use the driving directions to get the distance along a route - http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#RoutingDirections